# Use value in mongoose scope function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I'd like to find mails of a user by his id. But i have a problem because mongoose function is async.

```
Mail.find({receiver_id: '#id#'}, function(err, mails) {
    var result = [];
    var count = 0;
    if (mails.length > 0) {
        for (m of mails) {
            User.findById(m.sender_id, function(err, user) {
                if (user) {
                    result.push({
                        id: m._id,
                        title: m.title,
                        body: m.body
                    });
                    if (++count == mails.length) {
                        res.json({success: true, data: result});
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        res.json({success: false, error: 'Cannot find any email'});
    }
});
```

The problem is, when i got my result, all mails were the same. As i understood, because User.findById is an async function, so when i use **m** in that function, the **m** always represents the last child of **mails**.

I've figured out that if i pass some variables as the second param of findById function, it should work:

```
User.findById(m.sender_id, {id: m._id, title: m.title, body: m.body}, function(err, user) {
    if (user) {
        result.push({id, title, body});
        if (++count == mails.length) {
            res.json({success: true, data: result});
        }
    }
});
```

but because my document doesn't have only three fields, so i think there's another better solution.

How can i get it right ? Thanks !

Comment: Try use this module with your mails objects. https://github.com/caolan/async

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var async = require("async");
var yourResult = [];
async.each(mails, function(mailObj, done){
   User.findById(mailObj.sender_id, function(err, user) {
       //add data into result. call async callback function.
       done();
   })
}, function(err){
  //final callback write res here
  result.push(yourResult);
  res.json({success: true, data: result});
});
```

Async docs here. http://caolan.github.io/async/index.html
Hope this helps.

Comment: Exact what i need. Thank you very much !